# Springsource ToolSuite won't load after attempting to create database connection in Database Development Perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I added the Database Development perspective and tried to create my first Oracle database connection. I got a warning/error about being low on memory, and to read a particular Readme.Txt file.  I didn't note down the name, because I assumed a close/reopen the application would suffice.

Now, STS won't load at all.   Here's the contents of the .metadata/.log file.  I removed some of the stacktrace details to fit under the size requirement here.

I also got an Invalid registry object when merely attempting to select the Oracle Driver.  Is there a way to just reset some log or setting.  I'm really not looking forward to creating a new workspace and all that that entails.  It's  more than a little disapointing that just walking through a wizard turns my workspace into toast.

```
!SESSION 2013-05-13 14:40:00.963 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=2.9.2.201205071000-RELEASE
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-05-13 14:40:41.500
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-05-13 14:40:41.620
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.readArray(TableReader.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.basicLoadExtensionPoint(TableReader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.loadExtensionPoint(TableReader.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.loadExtensionPointTree(TableReader.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.load(RegistryObjectManager.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.basicGetObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.getObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensionPoint(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensions(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.internal.ui.services.MarkerNavigationService.initializeProviders(MarkerNavigationService.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.internal.ui.services.MarkerNavigationService.<init>(MarkerNavigationService.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.internal.ui.services.DataToolsUIServiceManager.<init>(DataToolsUIServiceManager.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.ui.services.IDataToolsUIServiceManager.<clinit>(IDataToolsUIServiceManager.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.server.internal.ui.explorer.providers.content.layout.AbstractLayoutProviderNav.<clinit>(AbstractLayoutProviderNav.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.server.internal.ui.explorer.providers.content.impl.ServerExplorerContentProviderNav.<init>(ServerExplorerContentProviderNav.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.server.internal.ui.explorer.providers.SQLModelContentProviderExtension.<init>(SQLModelContentProviderExtension.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.NavigatorContentDescriptor.createContentProvider(NavigatorContentDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.NavigatorContentExtension$1.run(NavigatorContentExtension.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.NavigatorContentExtension.internalGetContentProvider(NavigatorContentExtension.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$3.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 4 2013-05-13 14:40:42.456
!MESSAGE Exception occurred during problem detection:
----------------------------------- SOURCE BEGIN -------------------------------------
/**
 * 
 */
package com.mycompany.demand.history.rowmappers;

import com.mycompany.demand.history.exceptions.SkippedRecordException;
import com.mycompany.demand.history.models.DemandUnitDetailDto;
import com.mycompany.demand.history.parameters.ExecutionParameters;
import com.sap.conn.jco.JCoTable;

/**
 * @author Michael S. Davidson
 *
 */
public interface DemandHistRowMapper {

    public abstract DemandUnitDetailDto maprow(ExecutionParameters executionParmeters, JCoTable jcoTable, int row) throws SkippedRecordException, Exception;

    public static final String CS = "CS";
    public static final String EA = "EA";
    public static final String KEG = "KEG";
    public static final String BLANK = " ";
    public static final String N = "N";
    public static final String Y = "Y";
    public static final int ONE = 1;
    public static final int ZERO = 0;

}

----------------------------------- SOURCE END -------------------------------------
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2811)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2689)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2853)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1958)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getProjectCache(JavaProject.java:1920)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.newNameLookup(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2325)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 2 2013-05-13 14:40:42.461
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ui".
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process_aroundBody0(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process_aroundBody1$advice(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:269)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1876)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    ...
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 1005 2013-05-13 14:40:42.463
!MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1876)
    ...
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 1005 2013-05-13 14:40:42.463
!MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 0 2013-05-13 14:40:42.466
!MESSAGE Error in JDT Core during reconcile
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process_aroundBody0(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process_aroundBody1$advice(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:244)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 1005 2013-05-13 14:40:42.466
!MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2841)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2811)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2689)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2853)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1958)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getProjectCache(JavaProject.java:1920)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.newNameLookup(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2325)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process_aroundBody0(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process_aroundBody1$advice(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.initialProcess(MonoReconciler.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.initialProcess(JavaReconciler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:173)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 0 2013-05-13 14:40:43.931
!MESSAGE IOException encountered while reading "C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-2.8.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.mainData.903".
!STACK 0
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 20
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:639)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.readStringOrNull(TableReader.java:379)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 0 2013-05-13 14:40:43.955
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.Activator.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.InvalidRegistryObjectException: Invalid registry object
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.basicGetObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.getObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensionPoint(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:106)
    ... 19 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.InvalidRegistryObjectException: Invalid registry object
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.basicGetObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.getObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:262)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-05-13 14:40:44.257
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper$4
```

I added my full STS.INI file.

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_29/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

Comment: What are your `-xms` and `-xmx` settings in sts.ini?  When I see OutOfMemoryError, it is typically due to too little memory allocated by the `-xmx` value.  For example, I have mine set to 768, and have gone up to 1.5 when necessary

Comment: -Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m

Comment: -Xmn128m -Xms256m -Xmx768m are my values.  You'll notice, I added my full STS.ini file just above--in case you see somemthing else therer.  I changed the Xmx to 1024m but still didn't bring it up.  Anything bigger and I get a message saying JVM can't be created.  If I change the others, then STS throws up big Java Error box up.  I can open other workspaces just not the one where I added a dang database connections too.   If I can get back in I'm removing those immediately.  My laptop has 4g ram, fyi.

Comment: @Jason, I understand now what's happening.  I have a 32-bit 4g ram laptop.  I found a good article on it http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111697-How-to-change-memory-and-other-JVM-settings-for-STS.  I think I'm stuck.  Is it possible to manually remove these database connections from the database development perspective.  I'm almost positive that's what's killed me.

Comment: @Jason, what I did was create a new workspace, then import in the projects from the corrupted workspace (I guess it's corrupted), and began anew.